# Low RTD to google server

Tags: networking, internet, redirection

I'm trying to figure out how the RTD to the google servers can be so low:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.113.64): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.113.64: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=28.166 ms
```

`173.194.113.64` is registered in Mountain View, CA and I am in Germany. A ping to a host in California would be a lot longer. Issuing a traceroute gives me a hostname `fra02s21-in-f0.1e100.net`. I am asking myself what techniques they are using to redirect my request?

Comment: Are you asking who decides `google.com` is `173.194.113.64` (aka `fra02s21-in-f0.1e100.net`)? or who decides all the steps from your PC to `fra02s21-in-f0.1e100.net`?

Comment: For me, `173.194.113.64` is very near (RTD<30ms). Thus, it cannot be located in California as the packet would have to travel faster than light (I'm in germany). My question is: How does this work? I thought of some custom DNS servers that redirect the request!?

Comment: Europe to US should be around 60ms (one way). So Google probably has some cache-server on this side of the ocean (and it's just registered for Mountain View). How can you make sure the physical server is over there? (Mine goes to 82.94.234.57, some cache.google.com server here in The Netherlands) Never seen `fra02s21-in-f0.1e100.net` for Google before. What is you DNS-server? (That one determines where `google.com` goes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the RTD can't be < 30ms for the US. Europe to US should be around 60ms (one way).

So Google probably has some cache-server on this side of the ocean
(**and it's just registered for Mountain View while it really is in Europe**).

I found [this article](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/04/11/map-of-all-google-data-center-locations/) explaining it:

> **Google secrecy**
>
> Google has made it difficult both to find out where they keep their data centers and how many they have. One big reason for this is that almost all IP addresses that Google uses (and there are a lot of them) **are listed to their Mountain View, California address**, so just looking at IP addresses (with IP WHOIS or IP-to-location databases) **won’t help you figure out where their data centers are** or how many they have.
>
> In addition to this, Google usually seeks permits for their data center projects using companies (LLCs) that don’t mention Google at all, for example Lapis LLC in North Carolina and Tetra LLC in Iowa.
>
> Since Google tends to be quite secretive about their data centers in general, the information we have presented here most likely isn’t 100% complete.

Bonus link ;) [An inside look into the Data Centers of Google](http://www.google.com/about/datacenters/gallery/#/).

---

Here is [another source](http://www.wipmania.com/en/blog/why-worldip-data-rather-than-whois-data-examples/):

> 2) Large companies with offices worldwide do not share information about their real location in whois.
>
> - Example: Google Inc. has its data centers around the world, but whois always indicates its head office in Mountain View (California, USA). In reality, users from different countries will be send to the nearest data center. For a German e.g. the main page will be loaded from German data center (74.125.39.104).

---

**Edit:** (please keep in mind i'm not an expert on this topic:)

You are probably right about the "authoritative nameserver" doing some redirecting. I'm not sure if there are multiple servers behind **that** which do further redirection. You can do a `dig google.com +trace` to see from what server to what server your DNS-request goes. (Read [here](http://servermanagement24x7.com/dns-load-balancing-techniques-tips-and-tricks-using-dns-load-balancers.html) about some basics behind it)

As to the mechanism behind the redirection. You mentioned Akamai CDN. Google uses its own CDN. There were some rumors about Google buying Akamai a few years back but that didn't happen. I think Apple uses Akamai CDN (among some other CNDs).

On [this page](http://00f.net/2012/02/22/akamai-vs-public-dns-servers/) you can read Google uses  the "edns-client-subnet extension".

> OpenDNS and Google DNS have been supporting the edns-client-subnet extension for a long time. This mechanism was designed by Google specifically to address this problem. And it works beautifully. CDNs can send a redirection to the best server no matter what resolver you use.

With some further [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+edns-client-subnet+extension) you can learn more about this mechanisme. Like [here](http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2011/08/30/improving-dns-cdn-performance-with-edns-client-subnet/):

> Google, Bitgravity, CDNetworks, DNS.com and Edgecast have deployed support for [edns-client-subnet](http://www.afasterinternet.com/ietfdraft.htm). The idea is pretty simple. It passes part of your IP address (only part as to keep it semi-anonymous) in the request. A server that supports this extension can use it to geotarget and find a CDN node closest to you. Previously the best that could be done was using the location of the DNS server, which in many cases could be far away.

Another good read about CDNs and the edns-client-subnet extension is [this](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/which-cdns-support-edns-client-subnet/).

Enough reading material via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+edns-client-subnet+extension) ;)

Comment: This is a fairly good response, save as to say its probably not a cache server, more like an entire distribution network.

Comment: Yeah, maybe calling a Google entire network "a cache server" is a bit of an understatement :) But i guess many thousands of "cache servers" are (just a) part of Google's network of 900.000 servers (as of 2011). Found the locations of some large [data centers](http://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/index.html). But there are many, many smaller server-farms, located in probably every country.

Comment: The real question here is WHO redirects you to that nearby "cache" server (173.194.113.x for me) and HOW this is done. I think it may be a DNS-based approach where the authoritative nameserver uses metrics to determine which "cache server" to use (like Akamai CDN) but i'm not sure about that...

Comment: I added some information to Google's CDN and "edns-client-subnet extension" to my question. Please keep in mind i'm not an expert on this subject and have found this information through Googling a bit :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the digging! There is a corresponding IETF draft [here](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-subnet-02.txt)